# php, undefined index in Validation form

Tags: php, validation

could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this notice. i tried following the tutorial [here to create form validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRHma2JTiL4) but i'm getting

**"Notice: Undefined index: last_name in ...\workspace\Registration\registerValidation.php on line 53"**

```
    <?php

$errors = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //validation

    $testlName = $_POST['last_name'];       

    if(preg_match("([^A-Za-z0-9])", $testlName)){
        $errors['last_name'] = "Please enter a valid last name";
    }       

//more validation code


} 


function form_row_class($name){
        global $errors;
    return $errors[$name] ? "form_error_row" : "";
}

function error_for($name){
    global $errors;
    if($errors[$name]){  //this is line 53
        return "<div class='form_error'>".$errors[$name]. "</div>";
    }
}    

?>
<form  name="form1" method="post" action="registerValidation.php" >
<table class="form">
   <tr class="<?php echo form_row_class("last_name") ?>">
    <th><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></th>
    <td>
        <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($testlName)){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name']);}?>" />
        <?php if(isset($testlName)){echo error_for('last_name');}?>
    </td>
</tr>
           </table>


<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></p>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting that notice? I'm new to php so an explanation would be very well received, thanks!

~Myy

Comment: I'm getting many downvotes, I'm terribly sorry, Please tell me why this is a very bad question so that I may refrain from posting more like this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should probably be:

`if(isset($errors[$name])) {`

Currently you are testing for `$errors[$name]` being equal to true, which produces a notice if the value isn't set.

Likely the tutorial developer didn't realise because many people turn notices off. Although common it's not recommended practice - you should regard notices as errors.

Comment: And turning notices off is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: added to that "for development stages". It is very often forgotten to turn off again :P

Comment: @Jeffrey Edited to reinforce that point - definitely agree.

Comment: Which is line 53? Please mark it in your code!

Comment: it is marked it says "//this is line 53"

Comment: Philip, Thanks for the quick answer, I'm new to php so I'm having a hard time following some things. Thanks for helping me understand what was going on. on a related note, I'm getting a lot of downvotes, did I ask it in a wrong manner?

Comment: @Myy You posted a huge amount of code, most of which was irrelevant and only a comment on the actual line which line was causing the problem. In addition, for reference, no-one has time to run your code to reproduce the error. See http://sscce.org/ for advice on posting code when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I will edit my question to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!isset($last_name)) { echo "$last_name = ""; }
```

or;

if(empty($last_name)) { echo "$last_name = ""; }

Now is defined.